# MVC 4, EF 5 SaveChanges does not update database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm relatively new to this but I'm still a little embarrassed as this really should be simple...

All I'm trying to do is update an existing row in a database table. I'm using EF (5 I believe) code first.

For MVC 3 I used this approach (which worked):

```
ReportCommon reportcommon = db.ReportCommon.Single(r => r.ReportCommonId == id);
reportcommon.IP = StaticUtilities.GetIPAddress();
db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(reportcommon, EntityState.Modified);
db.SaveChanges();
```

I've tried a few examples that I've found and although they don't error the database doesn't get updated...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(CitizenEntryViewModel citizenDetails)
    {
        ActiveCitizen activeCitizen = db.ActiveCitizen.SingleOrDefault(m => m.ID == citizenDetails.ActiveCitizen.ID);

        if (activeCitizen != null)
        {
            citizenDetails.ActiveCitizen.CitizenUpdatedRecordOn = DateTime.Now;
            // Fields we don't edit but still need to pass back
            citizenDetails.ActiveCitizen.PublicID = activeCitizen.PublicID;
            citizenDetails.ActiveCitizen.IsKIN = activeCitizen.IsKIN;
            activeCitizen = citizenDetails.ActiveCitizen;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: There is no need to change the object state to `modified` manually. Is your `IP` property in the model correctly linked to the database?

Comment: Have you tried to change original `activeCitizen` object's properties and save it? Or call `db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(activeCitizen, EntityState.Modified);` before `db.SaveChanges();`?

Comment: Thanks. Silvermind, the first code example was taken from an MVC 3 project some time back. Zabavsky, I did try the approach of changing the state to `modified` but I didn't seem to have access to `ObjectStateManager`. VS Express 2012 says: 'ActiveCitizenSystem.Models.ACSEntities' does not contain a definition for ObjectStateManager. I do have the namespace entry: `using System.Data.Objects;`

Comment: OK, I've just seen that EF 4.0 uses the ObjectContext class where as the version 4.1 uses the DbContext class in which the methods like Set<T> and Entry are defined. As such I have used this syntax: `db.Entry(activeCitizen).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;` and now have an error message: "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this issue using the following code mentioned in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033638/an-object-with-the-same-key-already-exists-in-the-objectstatemanager-the-object) which shows how to save only the new values:

```
db.Entry(activeCitizen).CurrentValues.SetValues(citizenDetails.ActiveCitizen);
```

Note, I experienced the error: "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key"

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221349/an-object-with-the-same-key-already-exists-in-the-objectstatemanager-except) helped me overcome that issue.

The final code was therefore:

```
var currentCitizen = db.ActiveCitizen.Find(citizenDetails.ActiveCitizen.ID);
db.Entry(currentCitizen).CurrentValues.SetValues(citizenDetails.ActiveCitizen);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(CitizenEntryViewModel citizenDetails)
{
    ActiveCitizen activeCitizen = db.ActiveCitizen.SingleOrDefault(m => m.ID == citizenDetails.ActiveCitizen.ID);

    if (activeCitizen != null)
    {
        UpdateModel(activeCitizen);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: visit Joe Stevens blog to see how update model works.

http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/02/17/asp-net-mvc-using-controller-updatemodel-when-using-a-viewmodel/

Comment: Thanks. I tried the `UpdateModel` approach and received the following error: 'The model of type 'ActiveCitizenSystemMimic.Models.ActiveCitizen' could not be updated.' I have added an approach that works below. Many thanks.