# Exception on update using EF 4.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I am using EntityFramework code first approach. This is the method to insert and update:

```
 private void SaveCandidates(Container container, List<Candidate> candidates, bool isInsert)
    {

            var alreadyExists = false;

            foreach (candidate matchingOrderCandidate in candidates)
            {
                alreadyExists = container.Candidates.Any(i => i.Id == candidate.Id);

                if (!alreadyExists && isInsert)
                {
                    container.Entry(candidate).State = EntityState.Added;
                }

                if (alreadyExists && !isInsert)
                {
                    container.Entry(candidate).State = EntityState.Modified;

                }

            }
            container.SaveChanges();
    }
```

But in case of update, it throws exception

> [System.InvalidOperationException] = An object with the same key
>   already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

I first Insert Candidates and then some automatic process runs and then this method is called for update and in case of update I get exception at `container.SaveChanges()`. Any help will be highly appericiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the same issue already solved here [An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672255/an-object-with-the-same-key-already-exists-in-the-objectstatemanager-the-object)
try to use instead

```
container.Entry(candidate).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

this:

```
exist = container.Candidates.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == candidate.Id);
if(exist != null) container.Entry(exist).CurrentValues.SetValues(candidate);
```