# Unable to update an object , since its key already exists

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have the following method which is responsible to update an object:-

```
private TMSEntities tms = new TMSEntities();
//code goes here...    
public void InsertOrUpdateServer(TMSServer server, string username,long assetid)
    {
        // code goes here
        }
        else
        {
            var auditinfo = IntiateAudit(tms.AuditActions.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name.ToUpper() == "EDIT").ActionID,
            tms.TechnologyTypes.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name.ToUpper() == "Server").AssetTypeID,
            username, server.ServerID);
            server.IT360SiteID = resource.SITEID.Value;
            tms.Entry(server).State = EntityState.Modified;
            InsertOrUpdateAudit(auditinfo);
        }
    }
```

But I am getting the following error on the :-

```
tms.Entry(server).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.
>   The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same
>   key.  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: An object with
>   the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The
>   ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.
>
> Source Error:

Although I am tracking only one object, so how I can solve this problem?

**UPDATE**
I have added the following to my method:-

```
tms.Entry(server).CurrentValues.SetValues(server);
```

instead of

```
tms.Entry(server).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

but i am getting the following exception:-

> Member 'CurrentValues' cannot be called for the entity of type
>   'TMSServer' because the entity does not exist in the context. To add
>   an entity to the context call the Add or Attach method of
>   DbSet.

**Second update:-**

```
public Audit IntiateAudit(int actionId, int assettypeID, string username, int? technologyID)
        {


            TechnologyAudit ta = new TechnologyAudit();
            ta.ActionID = actionId;
            ta.AssetTypeID = assettypeID;  
            ta.DateTimeStart = DateTime.Now;
            ta.UserName = username;
            if (technologyID != null)
            {
                ta.TechnologyID = technologyID.Value;
            }

            return ta;


        }
```

&

```
public void InsertOrUpdateAudit(Audit ta)
        {
            if (ta.ID == default(int))
            {
                // New entity
                ta.DateTimeEnd = DateTime.Now;
                tms.TechnologyAudits.Add(ta);

            }
            else
            {
                // Existing entity
                tms.Entry(ta).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
```

&

```
public partial class TechnologyType
    {
        public TechnologyType()
        {
            this.SecurityroleTypePermisions = new HashSet<SecurityroleTypePermision>();
            this.Technologies = new HashSet<Technology>();
            this.TechnologyAudits = new HashSet<TechnologyAudit>();
        }

        public int AssetTypeID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<SecurityroleTypePermision> SecurityroleTypePermisions { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Technology> Technologies { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TechnologyAudit> TechnologyAudits { get; set; }
    }
```

&

```
public partial class TMSServer
    {
        public TMSServer()
        {
            this.TMSServers1 = new HashSet<TMSServer>();
            this.TMSVirtualMachines = new HashSet<TMSVirtualMachine>();
        }

        public int TMSServerID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ServerModelID { get; set; }
        public int DataCenterID { get; set; }
        public string ILOIP { get; set; }
        public int RackID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> StatusID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> BackUpStatusID { get; set; }
        public int RoleID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> OperatingSystemID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> VirtualCenterID { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public byte[] timestamp { get; set; }
        public long IT360SiteID { get; set; }

        public virtual DataCenter DataCenter { get; set; }
        public virtual OperatingSystem OperatingSystem { get; set; }
        public virtual ServerModel ServerModel { get; set; }
        public virtual Technology Technology { get; set; }
        public virtual TechnologyBackUpStatu TechnologyBackUpStatu { get; set; }
        public virtual TechnologyRole TechnologyRole { get; set; }
        public virtual TechnologyStatu TechnologyStatu { get; set; }
        public virtual TMSRack TMSRack { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TMSServer> TMSServers1 { get; set; }
        public virtual TMSServer TMSServer1 { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TMSVirtualMachine> TMSVirtualMachines { get; set; }
    }
}        }
```

**Third UPDATE**

the Audit code is :-

```
 public TechnologyAudit IntiateTechnologyAudit(int actionId, int assettypeID, string username, int? technologyID)
        {


            TechnologyAudit ta = new TechnologyAudit();
            ta.ActionID = actionId;
            ta.AssetTypeID = assettypeID;  
            ta.DateTimeStart = DateTime.Now;
            ta.UserName = username;
            if (technologyID != null)
            {
                ta.TechnologyID = technologyID.Value;
            }

            return ta;


        }
        public void InsertOrUpdateTechnologyAudit(TechnologyAudit ta)
        {
            if (ta.ID == default(int))
            {
                // New entity
                ta.DateTimeEnd = DateTime.Now;
                tms.TechnologyAudits.Add(ta);

            }
            else
            {
                // Existing entity
                tms.Entry(ta).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The context is not clear to me. tms is never set in this example. Could you edit the question so we could see a small example that compiles and produces the exception?

Comment: The tms is the context data class , it is set as follow :- ((private TMSEntities tms = new TMSEntities(); )). i have update my code

Comment: Have you seen the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672255/an-object-with-the-same-key-already-exists-in-the-objectstatemanager-the-object ???

Comment: Can you check my update..