# Multiple objects with the same key error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, object, model, dbcontext

Hi I'm getting following error while updating the record

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.
>   The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same
>   key.

Here's my Edit (Post) Action.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Type,Weightage,Description,ParentId")] HiringFactor hiringfactor)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var childCount = 0;
            var indent = "";
            var parentId = hiringfactor.ParentId;

            HiringFactor parentFactor = db.HiringFactors.Find(parentId);
            if (parentFactor != null)
            {
                childCount = parentFactor.ChildHiringFactors.Count;
                indent = parentFactor.Indent + "." + (childCount + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                var parentCount = db.HiringFactors.Count(hf => (hf.ParentId == null || hf.ParentId == 0));
                indent = (parentCount + 1).ToString();
            }
            hiringfactor.Indent = indent;

            db.Entry(hiringfactor).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.ParentFactors = new SelectList(db.HiringFactors, "Id", "IndentName", hiringfactor.ParentId);
        return View(hiringfactor);
    }
```

Is it becaus of I'm dealing with objects of Same Type within DB Context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems originated from `EntityState.Modified` before `SaveChanges` method, assuming `hiringfactor` is new entity as modification target:

```
db.Entry(hiringfactor).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

By convention, you can't re-attach a model once the entity has been loaded by the same key value. Try using this code right before `SaveChanges`:

```
db.Entry(parentFactor).CurrentValues.SetValues(hiringfactor);
```

Another way to set modified entity is using [`AsNoTracking`](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/advanced-entity-framework-scenarios-for-an-mvc-web-application) when doing `Find` method like this:

```
HiringFactor parentFactor = db.HiringFactors.AsNoTracking().Find(parentId);
```

Similar issues:

[An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672255/an-object-with-the-same-key-already-exists-in-the-objectstatemanager-the-object)

[An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585664/an-object-with-the-same-key-already-exists-in-the-objectstatemanager-the-object)

Comment: `var parentFactor = db.HiringFactors.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(hf => hf.Id == parentId);` This worked for me. Thank you  @tetsuya-yamamoto